# unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory while install bchlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, gcc, pip

I tried to install [bchlib](https://github.com/jkent/python-bchlib)

`pip install bchlib`
But I got error:

```
Complete output (10 lines):
running bdist_wheel                                                                                                                                                                                                                          running build                                                                                                                                                                                                                                running build_ext                                                                                                                                                                                                                            building 'bchlib' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
...........
unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I already install :
`apt install gcc libpq-dev python-dev python3-dev build-essential unixodbc-dev`

When I search I found that I have only

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-9
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-9
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-9
```

But I don't have `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc`